# core data delete not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I use the following code to populate a UITableView

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

test_coredataAppDelegate *appDelegate = (test_coredataAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self._context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"patients" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
self.PatientsList = [_context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
self.title = @"patients"; 
[fetchRequest release];
```

where PatientsList  is NSArray

when I want to delete record I use

```
[self._context  deleteObject:[_PatientsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSError *error; 

    if (![_context save:&error]) {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error series %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }

    [PatientsList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ; 


    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

but this doesn't have any effect.

How can I solve this issue and delete successfully, especially when my model contain relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you delete it from db but not from array so you need to delete from array or call database for again load the arry with new db details.

so for first approach delete it from array make your array mutable and use
`removeObjectAtIndex` method for deleting the object

or in second approach you need to fetch data again from core data.

and then reload table by using

```
[table reloadData];
```

Comment: Ah - I assumed he was talking about the underlying data model (i.e. if he did another fetch request he would see no difference between the new self.PatientsList and the old one).

Comment: I updated it but it cause the application to terminate any suggestion to solve that

Comment: update your code in question and give complete code where you make your array from database and where you delete the the object from core data

Comment: I update it , after reopen the application I find that the delete happened

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a little more information about the results you're getting from fetch requests before and after you call `deleteObject:`? You could also check the `userInfo` property of the *NSError* object that you pass to some Core Data functions as that often gives very help information in Core Data. Also remember that your modifications aren't "set in stone" until the data model is saved using the `save:` method of your *NSManagedObjectContext* instance.

The way Core Data handles the relationships of a deleted object is defined in your Core Data schema (.xcdata file), which you can edit in Xcode. You can set the delete action of relationships to "Deny", "Nullify", "Cascade" or "No Action" here. See the 'Relationship Delete Rules' section of the [documentation found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html).

Comment: I added if (![_context save:&error]) {
   // Handle error
   NSLog(@"Unresolved error series %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    
  }
But it cause the program to terminate without errors